# Good Security Strategy For This 2 Applications And 3 User Groups Situation

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, ldap

We have two web applications, A and B. Application A consumes the Rest APIs of application B. There are three user groups, or called roles from the security perspective in the whole system. Group 1 users use application A and group 2 and 3 users use application B. To consume Rest APIs of application B, the user needs to be in application B. Group 1 and 2 users are internal users while group 3 is external users. We have LDAP configured for application B. With this setup, internal users can sign into application B without creating new user credentials. And an internal user with admin rights can create a user account for an external user on application B.

Now, we need to solve an SSO problem so that a group 1 user can involve a REST API request with this user's user credentials on application A. There is an API to obtain an access token of those APIs with user credentials. One approach is to also have LDAP configuration on application A. It also is suggested to use OAuth2 such as Keycloak for SSO. But, accessing multiple applications is only applicable for group 1 users.

What will be a good security strategy for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred architecture in OAuth terms:

All apps manage logins via an Authorization Server such as Keycloak. Different apps / UIs are configured as 'clients' with whatever authentication methods make sense for the app's users. Some clients may use LDAP / automatic logins.

After authentication, an access token is returned to the client and can then be sent to APIs. The access token contains claims which can be anything that makes sense to your domain, eg 'user_role=default' for new users.

APIs can authorize based on claims received in access tokens, and in a same company situation it is common to forward the same token between microservices. In some cases a user could be authenticated but not authorized to use a particular app, in which case the app's API can return a 403 and the app can present an access denied page.

Note that in this setup the apps do not need to know anything about authentication specifics such as LDAP, since this is managed outside the app.

You may need to migrate to this type of solution gradually of course, since there is a learning curve, but it is worth trying to follow these patterns where you can, since it can provide powerful capabilities with only simple code. Have a look at these links for more details:

- [Authentication Concepts](https://curity.io/resources/learn/concepts-authentication/)
- [Token Concepts](https://curity.io/resources/learn/concepts-tokens/)